# Infer type argument of Interface from prop type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to make TS infer type argument of generic interface from type of it prop

```
interface I1<T> {
    prop: T
}

const i1: I1 = { prop: 'something' } // -> T is string
```

But this not work for interfaces. TS says

> Generic type 'I1' requires 1 type argument(s)

For functions this works

```
function f1<T>(arg: T): T { return arg }
const arg:string = 'something'
f1(arg) // returns string and T is string
```

So for functions TS just infers type argument, but for interface it doesn't. The question is, hot make TS infer type argument for interface? Any workarounds are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

you need to write the type of `T` when declaring a new variable

```
const i1: I1<string> = { prop: 'something' }; // add <string>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that this will work. But I want TS to infer type of `T` from type of `prop`. For function this perfectly works, but for interfaces this not works..

Answer (score 1):

The type for a variable is either inferred or specified from a type annotation. There is no middle ground in which you infer part of the type of a variable.

The only workaround (beside being explicit about the type) is to use a function, which are more flexible in regard to what gets inferred :

```
interface I1<T> {
    prop: T
}

function makeI1<T>(o: I1<T>) { return o}
const i1 = makeI1({ prop: 'something' }) // const i1: I1<string>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=65&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEYA8AVAfMgbwFgAoZc5ABygHtKAuZbUgX1NJgFcQExgaQyALZwA1hAw5cAChqNJeAJSFkUCGE5RBNNiQQCAzmGTB0yALzCxE9NIJVaDZAHIDNIeoAWoAObPkLMoA9EHI+iBGJujyWEZQvrhAA)

Or use an IIFE although that is arguably horrible for readability:

```
interface I1<T> {
    prop: T
}

const i1 = (<T>(o: I1<T>) => o)({ prop: 'something' }); // const i1: I1<string>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=80&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEYA8AVAfMgbwFgAoZc5ABygHtKAuZbUgX1NIRpAGcxlh0yALzIAFDlyiajDBICUw-DTmiCVWg2QBybjQC2EMAAtQAcy3IWcgNzIA9HeScefATKy8oZ3EA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure that I understand "The type for a variable is either inferred or specified from a type annotation. There is no middle ground in which you infer part of the type of a variable." Why are you talking about "infer part of the type of a variable"? When creating object of type `I1` I specify type of `T` by assigning value to `prop`. This definitely specify type of `T`

Comment: @Fyodor the type of `i1` has to be `I1<string>` you want to just specify the `I1<?>` and  let ts infer the `?` to string based on `value`. This is what i mean by it's all or nothing, you either let `i1` be completely inferred or you specify the whole type as `I1<string>`, you can partially specify it to `I1< ?>` and let ts fill in the blanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why type inference works for functions and not for interfaces? When I use `f1('something')` from my question, TS perfectly infer `T` to be string. And this is essentially the same as doing `const i1:I1 = ( prop: 'something' }`/ For function, I pass argument and type inferred, but for interface - is not